# Invalid username using snscrape for Twitter

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, twitter

When I enter a username that is clearly invalid, it returns a ValueError as expected. However, I can't seem to catch this error and do something about and the error is just shown on the terminal. This is the code I have so far.

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as twitterScraper

scraper = twitterScraper.TwitterUserScraper("ksdbdbkvbdvvbdvbsdvbvbdskbksd")

try:
    if scraper._get_entity():
        print(True)
except ValueError:
    print("Not found")
```

This should output "Not Found" but just outputs `ValueError: Invalid username`. Any help on how I can solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the error is on line of `scraper`

You have to add this line inside `try`

Like this:

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as twitterScraper

try:
    scraper = twitterScraper.TwitterUserScraper("ksdbdbkvbdvvbdvbsdvbvbdskbksd")
    scraper._get_entity()
except ValueError:
    print(True)
```

Comment: You are welcome. I also suggest to print something more specific like "Wrong username" since `True` can be confusing.